# Data migrations from virtuemart to magento

Tags: magento-1.9, migration

We are using Joomla 1.5.24 with Virtuemart 1.1.9 and we are looking for best way to migrate our data to magento enterprice latest version (1.9) . Is there any how-to guide?

Answer (score 2):

I just have something similar to this. I would recommend to use jSON API. Processes will be below::

1. Write php script to produce jSON data, from Joomla/Virtuemart.
2. Write php script to insert data to your magento database.

The other way would be export your data in CSV, and import it in magento.

Hope that helps, and please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I tried to export both in csv & sql but virtuemart products database tables & fields do not match magento ones. As for your suggestion, has you already developed such a script?

Comment: Yes, it imports into magento from a csv file, But I can help you importing. Also exporting into CSV should not be a big deal, If you can get it on csv you can get it on jSON API as well .. so its really easy.

Comment: @m82amjad  .... If you did this can you please guide or can provide script to do that?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to write the scripts by your own, create some products of the type you want to import in your Magento Shop, export them as csv and write your script accordingly to produce the right structure of the csv file.

Another way would be to use available extensions, but you have to check if they fit do your Versions of Shops, maybe cart2cart is one of them.

Hope i could help

Comment: cart2cart needs about $200 and most important i dont like the idea that all my data will go through their service.

Comment: @HaCos you'd be mad no to pay the $200 for cart2cart to do it for you. It's 100% safe, and they'll help you with any problems. It's sounds like you don't know an awful lot about Magento, so do the sensible thing and let someone else do it for you. That's my advice.

Comment: @Samir Shaban  .....How about this Vm2Mage (link yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/vm2mage). I am looking to good service or extension for migration but cart2cart response not seems good. Any more suggestion form your side would be great.