# Copy/import or migrate joomla articles to Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, import, migration, cms-block

i am looking to migrate article of joomla to magento. We can display articles of joomla in cms or static blocks. Is there any way or method to achieve this?

Magento: 1.9.2.1
Joomla:  2.5.27

Is it possible if we can import articles from joomla in csv or any other format which we later can import in magento?

***Update:***

This question is not duplicate of [Data migrations from virtuemart to magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/24812/29175) becaue its specific to migration/copy of articles.

There are lot of extensions and services available to migrate products,customers and orders from joomla to magento but noboday talks about articles of joomla import. Nobody is ready to import articles so this question is different and specific.

Answer (score 1):

Magento has no builtin function to import CMS block therefore there are two possible way to import them:

1. By a php script
2. Inserting directly in database

I suggest to export the Joomla articles from the db into an intermediate migration file format, write an import script in Magento.